# window.location url pulling in entire code snippet?

Tags: javascript, webflow

I apologize because this is likely a very simple problem, but I'm not a developer. I'm using this code to pull a random CMS item from a collection in Webflow when clicking a button, but when I click the button, the url ends up including the entire code snippet in it. Why is this happening? How do I specify that I want the url variable to end after randomSlug?

Live example: https://flashcards-93432a.webflow.io/study
Example url it points to: `https://flashcards-93432a.webflow.io/laws-of-ux/%20const%20randomButton%20=%20document.querySelector('#random-button')const%20slugs%20=%20document.querySelectorAll('.slug')const%20randomIndex%20=%20Math.floor(Math.random()%20*%20slugs.length)const%20randomSlug%20=%20slugs[randomIndex].textContentconst%20url%20=%20%22https://flashcards-93432a.webflow.io/laws-of-ux/%22%20+%20randomSlug;randomButton.addEventListener('click',%20()%20=%3E%20{window.location%20=%20url})`

```
<script> 
const randomButton = document.querySelector('#random-button')
const slugs = document.querySelectorAll('.slug')
const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * slugs.length)
const randomSlug = slugs[randomIndex].textContent

const url = "https://flashcards-93432a.webflow.io/laws-of-ux/" + randomSlug;

randomButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    window.location = url
})
</script>
```

Comment: I looked at your website and the javascript you are running exists in a div **<div class="slug w-embed w-script">** . Which has the class of SLUG, so when you get the contents of the slug divs, you are going to get the script as it exists within a div with the class of slug

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! I was misunderstanding the directions and was adding the .slug class to the wrong HTML Embed item.

Fixed the issue by changing the class on the javascript embed to something unique and adding the .slug class to the embed within each collection list item. It's now working properly. Thanks all!

https://flashcards-93432a.webflow.io/study